# Chrome - DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist

Tags: google-chrome, selenium

**My system:**

- Ubuntu 20.04 (AWS)
- Python 3.8.5
- ChromeDriver 88.0.4324.96
- Google Chrome 88.0.4324.182

**Error:**  unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist
The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.

Code:

```
async def arsenic_scraper(url):
    service = services.Chromedriver()
    browser = browsers.Chrome()
    browser.capabilities = {"goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]}}
    async with get_session(service, browser) as session:
        await session.get(url)
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error?

Comment: Termina i guess.
running telegram bot python app though supervisorctl, saving all errors in logfile_err.log

Answer (score 4):

```
browser.capabilities = {"goog:chromeOptions": {"args": ["--headless", "--no-sandbox", "--disable-dev-shm-usage"]}}
```

This helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling Chrome. Press:
CTRL+T
Then enter the commands:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install WhateverChromeIsCalledOnDownload
```

You can get the package name by viewing the package that you downloaded. Make sure you get it exactly right or the command will not work.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Didn't helped. Any other ideas?

Comment: I will have to do some research. I will get back to you on that.

Comment: What if you tried

    sudo apt-get install DevToolsActivePort

Comment: Another thing you could possibly do is check the file in the Synaptic Package Manager. Here is a guide to help install it: https://itsfoss.com/synaptic-package-manager/

Then, if you decide to install it, you could search DevToolsActivePort

Comment: Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: that didnt work, but i find solution